# How to make Hibernate not drop tables

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate and whenever I try to add a record it drops the table and adds it again. It never uses the existing table and make changes on that.

This is the relevant part of my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name = "current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <!-- Mapping the entities -->
<mapping class="inputDetails.Table1"/>
<mapping class="inputDetails.Table2"/>


  <!--mapping resource="contact.hbm.xml"/-->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is how I save data:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
//...
session.save(newrecord)
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

tells hibernate to update the database schema each time the session factory is created.

And

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

builds a new session factory.

A `SessionFactory` should be built only once during the wole application lifetime. It should be created once and then reused. Have you read the [hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/)?

Comment: Is there a way to make the session load the already existing database contents? There are values in the database after the application stops running, and when I start the application again I want it to add records on top of what is already in the database.

Comment: Read my answer again, and read the reference manual. Using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=auto, you're telling hibernate to update the schema each time you create a session factory. So it recreates the table. This is useful for quick tests with an empty database. If you have some data you want to keep, alter your schema manually and remove this configuration option from your config file.

Comment: Oh alright, I was confused because I thought that property was used to keep contents from database instead of recreating it (something i read from somewhere else and I guess it turns out to be the opposite of what I thought). Thanks I will try your solution when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it gets overwritten or does it not commit? I mean are you commiting your transactions?

Maybe try something in the lines of:

```
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // Do some work
    factory.getCurrentSession().load(...);
    factory.getCurrentSession().persist(...);

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

Comment: I did have the transaction commit. I forgot to put it in my post. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();

config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
new SchemaExport(config).drop(false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="META-INF/import.sql" />
```

the first time I deployed. This created my desired schema and populate it with data. The second time I changed to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

and redeployed. Obviously the tables were dropped. I switched to `create` for the first deployment and stayed with `update` with the redeployments. This time tables were not dropped and data stayed untouched.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotations try this:

```
Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
// your props ...
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

// or use Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO from org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
hibernateProperties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
```