# How to prevent database renewing its data in camunda

Tags: mysql, wildfly, camunda

I am using 
 - camunda-bpm-wildfly-7.4.0
 - mysql-5.6.24-winx64
 - wildfly-8.2.1.Final
I have integerated mysql with camunda wildfly.
My datasource code in the standalone.xml is as follows,

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine" pool-name="ProcessEngine" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/camundabpm?DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
```

How do I prevent the database resetting on server restart? It removes all data and replaces it with new data on every server start. So I am unable to persist my data between server on and off.

**Update:**
I found out that hibernate was deleting the tables from the db So I changed the property from this 
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />` 
to 
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />` 
after having a look at  [How to make Hibernate not drop tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611437/how-to-make-hibernate-not-drop-tables). But now the tasklist process instances are removed and only the tables created by my project remain and all other tables are refreshed with new data.

Comment: What do you mean with database resetting? What and when is this happening? Also you can remove these parameters which are H2 settings and not mysql: `?DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

Comment: By resetting I mean that its data is refreshed in the database. Regarding the h2, I agree with that. I have added autoconnect=true parameter. But still the data in tasklist and even process variables get refreshed on restarting the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the value of the `databaseSchemaUpdate` poroperty? It should be contained in the standalone.xml of our WildFly (very down). Make sure it os not set to `create-drop`.

See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/deployment-descriptors/tags/process-engine/#configuration-properties

Comment: I don't see the `databaseSchemaUpdate` property but I am able to the following property `<property name="isAutoSchemaUpdate">true</property>` . Should I change anything over here?

Comment: In this case I would add "databaseSchemaUpdate" and give it the value "true". This is like "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" with value="update".